# Finding Inverse Laplace Transform using Taylor Series

Tags: laplace-transform

Find the inverse Laplace transform

$F(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}(s^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{s}})$

using each of the following techniques:

1. Expand the exponential in a Taylor series about s=∞, and take inverse Laplace transforms term by term (this is allowable since the series is uniformly convergent.).
2. Sum the resultant series in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: That looks doable. What part have you problems with?

Comment: Expanding the exponential in a Taylor series about s=∞.

Comment: Ah. You know $e^z = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}z^n$, I suppose. Just insert $z = -\frac1s$ and you have it.

Comment: I am just stuck here: after expanding I am getting the series as :1/s^.5 -1/s^1.5 + 1/s^2.5 ..so on.Now, I think I just need to manipulate it, so that I can use this formula:1/s^(n+1)=(t^n)/n!..But somehow could not able to translate into that form.Any help please?

Comment: What is the inverse Laplace transform of $s^{-\alpha}$ generally?

Comment: Something which I am not too sure!Is it delta(t-c)?Can you pls help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the gamma function to find the inverse of each of the 1/sqrt(s) instead of the basic integer factorial. then take out a common factor of sqrt(t) and find a general series sum from n=0 to infinity. you also seem to be missing a 1/n! in the series.

then use the given gamma formula from the standard formulae to sub for the Gamma(n+1/2) function. you can then use wolfram to get a standard function that the series will converge to.

Then suggest what I can do for part b :)

Comment: I have done this:We know, Taylor Series:〖 e〗^z=∑_(n=0)^∞▒1/n! z^n   
Here, we take z=-1/s 
So, L^(-1) {s^(-1/2) e^(-1/s)}
=L^(-1) {〖(-z)〗^(-1/2) 1/n!  z^n}
=- L^(-1) {1/n! 1/√z   z^n} 
=-[L^(-1) { z^(-1/2)  z^1}  - L^(-1) {1/2!  z^(-1/2)  z^2} + …  ]
=-[L^(-1) {1/1! z^(1/2) } - L^(-1) {1/2! z^(3/2) } + L^(-1) {1/2! z^(5/2) }-…]

Comment: Now what?I am not sure about Gama Function?Is there anyway I can do inverse Laplace transform of s−α generally?

Comment: You should have $s^{-1/2}*exp(-1/s) = 1/s^{1/2} - 1/s^{3/2} + 1/(2!s^{5/2})+...$ etc.. 

then $L^{-1} {1/s^n} = t^{n-1}/Gamma(n)$ from Spiegel.

Apply the inverse to the series and solve one by one. 
then take out a common factor of $1/t^{0.5}$

Comment: The series sum should be $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-t)^n/(Gamma(n+1/2)*n!)$

Enter the given formula for gamma(n+1/2), simplify a little and enter that series into wolfram. you should get a fairly standard function

Comment: How you are deducing that the series sum should be ∑∞n=0(−t)n/(Gamma(n+1/2)∗n!)?Also Gamma
(n+1/2),I could not find any formula for that.But as in Wolfram I got:(2 (n+0.5)!)/(2 n+1)

Comment: My series looks like this:(1/sqrt(t))/sqrt(pi)-2×sqrt(t)/sqrt(pi)+4/3×t^(3/2)/(2! sqrt(pi))-8/15×t^(5/2)/(3! sqrt(pi))+...  and in wolfram it says 'Unable to determine general term',so was wondering how you have determined?Can you please share?

Answer (score 3):

We know that
$$ \displaystyle \mathcal{L} \{t^{n-1}\} = \frac{\Gamma(n)}{s^{n}}, n>0 ,s>0 $$
$$ \frac{1}{s^n} = \frac{\displaystyle \mathcal{L} \{t^{n-1}\}}{\Gamma(n)} $$
$$ \displaystyle \mathcal{L^{-1}} \{\frac{1}{s^n}\} = \frac{t^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n)} $$
Therefore
$$ \displaystyle \mathcal{L^{-1}} \{ s^{-1/2} e^{-1/s} \} = \displaystyle \mathcal{L^{-1}} \{ \frac{1}{s^{1/2}} - \frac{1}{s^{3/2}} + \frac{1}{(2!s^{5/2})} + ... + (-1)^{n}\frac{1}{n! s^{n+\frac{1}{2}}} \} $$
$$ = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!} \displaystyle \mathcal{L^{-1}} \{\frac{1}{s^{n+\frac{1}{2}}}\} $$
$$ = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!} \frac{t^{n-\frac{1}{2}}}{\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2})} $$
But after this I don't know how to simplify

Answer (score -1):

$\frac{\cos 2(\sqrt{t})}{\sqrt{\pi t}}$

Comment: I know the answer can be determined directly from the Wolfram, but that is not what I am suppose to do.:)

Comment: It is also in the tables from Spiegel

Comment: I know,but I have to 'proof' it!